# Comparing Two Urls Using Reverse And HTTP_REFERER

Tags: django, django-urls

I am wanting to prevent a user from accessing a certain page unless they have been redirected. In order to do this I thought id do this:

```
if(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') != reverse('some_page')):
        return redirect('some_page')
```

This works almost perfectly except that `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` returns the whole url address, while `reverse('some_page')` returns the abbreviated url.

For example

`request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` returns`http://127.0.0.1:8000/page_one/some_page/`

`reverse('some_page')` returns`/page_one/some_page/`

How can I either add the (sorry but I dont know the correct term) first part of the url (http://127.0.0.1:8000) to `reverse('some_page')`, or remove it from `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` so they can be both compared in the if statement please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works :)

```
if(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') != request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('some_page'))):
        return redirect('some_page')
```